# pgsql select largest item in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I create table like

```
CREATE TABLE dataset (
  identifier character varying(15) NOT NULL,
  description character varying(3000) NOT NULL,
  publisher character varying(45) NOT NOT NULL,
  publication_date date,
  modification_date date,
  title character varying(600) NOT NULL,
  release_date date
)
```

How can I select biggest identifier
eg.

```
10001/01
10001/02
10001/03
10001/04
```

choose 10001/04

Comment: identifier eg 100010/0001,   100010/0002....

Comment: I need get the largest one behind /. like 100010/111, in all 111 items

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a piece of text (varying(15)) as identifier? It's common to use a number that gets the next number from a sequence. Use data type SERIAL and this is all handled for you, see the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

You can also use MAX() to get the largest number, but never ever try to use this as "the next number" because that doesn't work. There might be others working on the same number...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
select parts[1], max(parts[2])
from ( 
   select identifier,
          regexp_split_to_array(identifier, '/')::int[] as parts
   from dataset 
) t
group by parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a syntax error there, `NOT NOT NULL` on line 4.

If you by "largest" means "longest", then something like this may help you out:

```
select identifier from dataset order by length(identifier) desc limit 1;
```

If you want the "biggest" item in a text comparation format (i.e. "foo">"bar"), then use MAX:

```
select max(identifier) from dataset;
```

This will also help if identifier is numeric in string format (caveats ... I did once experience '-1'>'0' due to some strange locale setting ... and '9'>'10').

You may also cast identifier to an int on the fly if it's numeric:

```
select max(identifier::int) from dataset;
```

Given the extra info that it's a wish to compare the number after the slash, try this:

```
select identifier from dataset 
order by substring(identifier from '/([0-9]*)$')::int desc limit 1;
```

To speed that up, you may add an index on the substring expression:

```
create index dataset_by_substring on dataset 
(substring(identifier from  '/([0-9]*)$'));
```

Comment: hi tobixen the identifier contain / but i want to get the biggest one compare the number after /. such as 10001/01< 10001/02 choose 10001/02

Comment: I'd use a regexp for that ... I'll add it to my answer in some minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(
       substring(
                 identifier, 
                 position('/' in identifier) + 1, 
                 length(identifier) - position('/' in identifier)
                )::integer
      )
```

I know it's not so beautiful.